# mysql permissions needed to do a ALTER TABLE in database

Tags: mysql, permissions

```
grant LOCK TABLES, SELECT,ALTER,INSERT,CREATE ON `databasetoupgrade%`.* to 'someuser'@'localhost';
```

those are the privileges I gave a users that needs to be able to ALTER a table (add columns, ...)

the mysql documentation states that alter, insert, create is needed, but even with lock tables and select permissions, I still get the error that the user does not have enough permissions to do ALTER.

When I give the user all privileges on those tables/databases is works.

Does anyone know what the EXACT privileges are that I need to do ALTER? Of which one did I forget in the list above?

This post can be closed, this fixed it:

grant ALTER, LOCK TABLES, SELECT, INSERT, CREATE

I might have screwed up somewhere in my previous commands...

Comment: Are you restarting the database each time you make changes?

Comment: What is exact error you are getting?  And how is the user trying to access the database?

Comment: I'm not restarting it. It's a PHP script that execute's the ALTER command as a mysql user I pass in the script. Perhaps ALTER triggers a restart of the database?

Comment: I think he means, are you restarting the database after issuing the GRANT command?

Comment: I restarted mysqld after the GRANT

Answer (score 2):

These grants now work fine (for backups) + ALTER command:

grant ALTER, LOCK TABLES, SELECT, INSERT, CREATE